# How do you import npm modules in javascript for a non-app website?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, npm

## My situation:

I already have a website setup. I am trying to add react to a single page within it without starting from scratch (ie create a new react app and rebuilding my website). Here is a brief layout of my website:

[image]

`assets/js/AlgoSort.js` is the output from AlgoSort.js in the `assets/js/src-jsx/` directory where babel converts the original AlgoSort.js to jsx and outputs it into the `assets/js/` directory.

The `Interactive_Sorting_Algorithms.html` uses `AlgoSort.js`.

Currently, the way I have been able to import my npm modules has been to add the following to the bottom of `Interactive_Sorting_Algorithms.html` while inside the `<body>` tag:

```
    <script src="/node_modules/react/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/konva/konva.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/react-konva/lib/ReactKonvaCore.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/AlgoSort.js" crossorigin></script>
```

This **WORKS**, however it is not ideal and can be tedious and unreliable.

## The Goal

I want to be able to import the npm modules (ex: react) from within import  from '' or simply with `require` if possible.

(I just don't want to have to add a `<script>` tag at the bottom of my html file everytime I want to use a new npm module)

## The Problems

When I try to use `import React from '/node_modules/react'` (after removing the `<script>` tags from the `Interactive_Sorting_Algorithms` file) I get errors saying:

`Uncauaght SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

In response to this I changed `<script src="/assets/js/AlgoSort.js" crossorigin></script>` to `<script type="module" src="/assets/js/AlgoSort.js" crossorigin></script>` in `Interactive_Sorting_Alogorithms.html`. After doing this I get a new error saying:

`Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

After looking around the interwebs I found that to fix that error you would have to set the `type` of script to javascript. But if I do that I get the module error. And I end up in a loop.

The final solution I tried to do was to have the following setup:

Interactive_Algorithms_Sort.html

```
<script type="module" src="/assets/js/AlgoSort.js" crossorigin></script>
```

AlgoSort.js (not yet compiled to be jsx)

```
import React from '/node_modules/react/umd/react.production.min.js';
import ReactDOM from '/node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js';
```

This setup does get me closer to what I am looking for, however it throws the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/react/umd/react.production.min.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

## Conclusion

So now that I have laid out my problems, hopefully someone can help me by either helping me figure out what I am doing wrong, or letting me know if this is even possible within an already setup website.

Thank you in advance for anyone who can help me understand my problem.  :)

Let me know if further clarification is needed.

Comment: It sounds like you need to bring in a bundler such as webpack (https://webpack.js.org/). This will allow you to `import` in your source code - it then stiches together all of the relevant javascript (and optionally css/images/etc..) into a single file which is delivered to the browser.

Comment: This sort of stuff (babel/webpack/modules) can be tricky to get set up, and I know you don't want to rewrite the app from scratch but if you're looking for a quick win in future something like [create react app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) does an excelent job of bootstrapping all of this to let you focus on writing your code